# PyMongo : Read MongoDB Query from text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I want to store a MongoDB query (pipeline) in a text file, and then read it into some data structure etc. in my python script. and then, run that aggregation query using PyMongo.

So, in short, read mongo query from file and execute it.

I keep getting the error:

> no pipeline object detected

```
data=database.collection.aggregate( sqlData ) query --- { 
"$match": { 
"$and": [
{ 
    "application": d['application'], 
    "process": { "$in": d['process'] }, 
    "startDate": { "$gte": date_low, "$lte": date_hi } }] } 
}, 
{ '$unwind': "$role" }, 
{ '$unwind': "$role.steps" }, 
{ '$unwind': "$role.steps.childData" }, 
{ "$project": { "_id": 0, "ID": "$id", } },
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you are working with?

Comment: @MartinKondor
python script for d in data:

#=== MongoDB Query Starts ===#
        data=database.collection.aggregate( sqlData )


query ---
{
  "$match": {
    "$and": [{
      "application": d['application'],
      "process": {
        "$in": d['process']
      },
      "startDate": {
        "$gte": date_low,
        "$lte": date_hi
      }
    }]
  }
},

{
  '$unwind': "$role"
}, {
  '$unwind': "$role.steps"
}, {
  '$unwind': "$role.steps.childData"
},

{
  "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "ID": "$id",
  }
},

Comment: Whats the type of `sqlData`?

Comment: @MartinKondor `with open('temp.sql', 'r') as file:      sqlData = file.read().splitlines() `